# passing variables to graphql in php

Tags: php, graphql, php-curl

I just want to confirm my understanding of how to pass graphql variables from php into a graphql query. I am using php Curl to perform my request to the graphql api server.

```
   $data='
    query($businessId : ID!, $page : Int!, $pageSize : Int!) {
       business(id: $businessId) {
          id
          isClassicInvoicing
          invoices(page: $page, pageSize: $pageSize) {'
  ...

  $variables=array(
    '$businessId'=>'"xxxx"',
    '$page'=>1,
    '$pageSize'=>5);

  $payData = urlencode($data);
  $payVariables = urlencode(json_encode($variables));
  $apiURL=$apiURL . '?' . "query=".$payData."&variables=".$payVariables ;
```

The error I get is - Variable "$page" of required type "Int!" was not provided. I receive this error for $businessId and $pageSize also.

Comment: grphql works over POST, not GET

Comment: thanks @xadm - the get request is correct the issue was the structure of the variables array. I will post in the answer below.

Comment: GET has drawbacks, f.e. url length, should be avoided, limited to very simple use cases ... and you can use ` $variables=(object)array(` - will be json-ed as object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of $variables was not correct. The correct way is

```
$variables='
{
  "businessId": "xxxx",
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 5
}';
```